# Elasticsearch getting rid of duplicated result

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Given the following documents:

```
name: Peter, enterTime: 2022-01-27
name: Peter, enterTime: 2022-01-28
name: Peter, enterTime: 2022-01-29
name: Jenny, enterTime: 2022-01-29
name: Jenny, enterTime: 2022-01-30
name: Peter, enterTime: 2022-01-31
name: Peter, enterTime: 2022-02-01
name: Jenny, enterTime: 2022-02-02
name: Jenny, enterTime: 2022-02-03
```

I want to write a elasticsearch query to group the result by name if the next result is the same, and only display the first result.
Result that I am expecting:

```
name: Peter, enterTime: 2022-01-27
name: Jenny, enterTime: 2022-01-29
name: Peter, enterTime: 2022-01-31
name: Jenny, enterTime: 2022-02-02
```

I have tried aggregation query and collapse but I failed miserably so far. Any tips would be very appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by next result is same? you mean enter data is next date?

Comment: what query you are trying to execute ? because this orer may be change based on your query ?

Comment: i mean if the name is the same, like grouping Peter and Jenny together

Comment: the query i am running is sorting by enterTime asc. But I want to get rid of result that has the same name as the previous result.

Comment: i dont think so you can achive with elastic inbuild functionality. you need to write logic at application end.